# I stored more data on VRAM than it's actual size. How is that possible?

Tags: opengl, memory, gpu, vbo

I was analysing performance of my simple voxelized world renderer. I wanted to find performance limits for a different techniques, a kind of stress test. At some point I found something really wierd. I was allocating geometry data in chunks using different VBO for each chunk. I'm using a few counters programmed into the engine that helped me see what is happening with the data.

So here I was trying to allocate *664* chunks containing *1 199 824* voxels altogether which are built using *28 795 776* vertices. 
Each vert consists of *3* floats for position, *3* floats for normal vector and *4* floats for RGBA color. Float is apparently *4* bytes of size, so based on that I calculated estimated memory size of this whole world to be roughly *1098Mb* ( vertexcount * 3 * 4 * 2 + vertexCount * 4* 4). 
I ran the program just fine at amazing speed of 7 FPS, but it worked and looked as it should. The problem is I'm using GiGabyte GeForce GTX 460 OC2 with 1 GB of Video Memory. Then how was I able to allocate trough VBO 1098Mb of data? 
Is the data cached of compressed somehow once inside VRAM? 
 Or maybe there is a few Mb of reserve memory that I had no idea about? Is the only explanation that my counters are giving me the wrong results or hopefully there is something I don't know aobut video memory management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is that VRAM you're talking about? **;)**

OpenGL has no concept of VRAM or graphics card local memory. There's just "memory" in OpenGL, that's purely abstract. Data can be swapped from the GPU local memory to system memory and back as needed.

If the hardware supports it (and the GTX460 does!) textures can even be larger than the available GPU local memory and the required texture subdata gets swapped in on demand.

Comment: So you're saying that when I'm filling VBOs it does not necessarily store the data on graphics card memory? I thought it was the purpose of using it. So how can I be sure wheather my data is actually stored on a graphic card? When does the swap happen and under what conditions? I'm really curious!

Comment: Just like you can allocate swap space on the disk for when your CPU runs out of RAM, if the GPU runs out of available memory, it can temporarily move some infrequently used data there, and reload it when it's needed. When this happens is (intentionally) left to the drivers and GPU, and I don't think OpenGL exposes a mechanism to get whether or not a section of memory is actually on the GPU.

Comment: So it seems I can't really run out of memory, Can I? I'm really interested what is the performance cost of that swap, I'm definitely going to dig more into the topic. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @Shilghter: You're mostly constraint by the peripheral bus bandwidth. Of course there are also the access latencies involved with that, but those you'd only feel if the peripheral bus would be orders of magnitude faster. And you can of course run out of memory. You have only so much system RAM and disk swap :)

Comment: GPUs can also read data directly from system memory. Not everything it uses **has** to be in VRAM.